# Running Object Table, get Object back by a special Process Id

Tags: c#, com, process

I have some trouble. I want to start Processes with C# (The goal is to start several applications of a special Document in the background). Now this is done by me, I start the Program as a invisible Process, but I want to direct the application through my code. So, I want to have a object back (the object with a special Process-ID), which is lying on the Running Object Table. I don't can solve this, because I am getting always the first application back.

```
public static Application GetRunningCOMObjectByProcessId(int id)
        {
            // ROT-Schnittstelle
            IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable = null;

            // Moniker-Auflistung
            IEnumMoniker monikerList = null;

            try
            {
                // Running Object Table abfragen und nichts zurückgeben, wenn keine COM-Objekte laufen
                if (GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable) != 0 || runningObjectTable == null) return null;

                // Moniker abfragen
                runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerList);


                // An den Anfang der Auflistung springen
                monikerList.Reset();

                // Array für Moniker-Abfrage erzeugen
                IMoniker[] monikerContainer = new IMoniker[1];

                // Zeiger auf die Anzahl der tatsächlich abgefragten Moniker erzeugen
                IntPtr pointerFetchedMonikers = IntPtr.Zero;

                // Alle Moniker durchlaufen
                while (monikerList.Next(1, monikerContainer, pointerFetchedMonikers) == 0)
                {
                    // Objekt für Bindungsinformationen
                    IBindCtx bindInfo;

                    // Variable für den Anzeigenamen des aktuellen COM-Objekts
                    string displayName;

                    // Bindungsobjekt erzeugen
                    CreateBindCtx(0, out bindInfo);

                    // Anzeigename des COM-Objekts über den Moniker abfragen
                    monikerContainer[0].GetDisplayName(bindInfo, null, out displayName);

                    // Bindungsobjekt entsorgen
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bindInfo);
                    /*
                    // Wenn der Anzeigename mit dem gesuchten übereinstimmt ...
                    if (displayName.IndexOf(objectDisplayName) != -1)
                    {
                        // Variable für COM-Objekt
                        object comInstance;

                        // COM-Objekt über den Anzeigenamen abrfragen
                        runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikerContainer[0], out comInstance);

                        // COM-Objekt zurückgeben
                        return comInstance;
                    }
                    */
                    // Variable für COM-Objekt
                    object comInstance;
                    Application qvApp;
                    // COM-Objekt über den Anzeigenamen abrfragen
                    runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikerContainer[0], out comInstance);

                    if (comInstance is Application)
                    {
                        qvApp = (Application)comInstance;
                        int pid = qvApp.GetProcessId();
                        if (pid == id)
                        {
                            return qvApp;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Nichts zurückgeben
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ggf. COM-Verweise entsorgen
                if (runningObjectTable != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(runningObjectTable);
                if (monikerList != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(monikerList);
            }
            // Nichts zurückgeben
            return null;
        }
```

So, how can I get a certain object back with a special process id???

## Edit (How looks my ROT)

I am interested in the yellow one's.
[image]

Comment: This **must** be taken care of by the server itself, COM intentionally avoids giving you any knowledge of the process itself.  It is the point of a moniker, a distinguishing name for a particular server instance.  If you want the process ID to be important then it can be encoded in the moniker name.  It is very rarely useful since you'd normally have a hard time obtaining a specific PID.

Comment: Hello @Hans Passant; could you post me some example, how I can encoded the process ID in the moniker name

Comment: I seriously doubt that would be helpful.  You need to post the *server* code first, you've only shown client code.  The usual hang-up is that you can't change it.  If you can change it then just append the value you obtain from GetCurrentProcessId(), converted to ascii.

Comment: @HansPassant, so if I can't change this (that's my case), it is not possible to get a elective object back